# Setting password on sudo su for Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, password, sudo

Our staging server is on an Amazon EC2 instnace.  When you ssh into it you can execute a `sudo` command or `sudo su` without having to enter a password.

Is there anyway I can require a password from a user when they try a command with `sudo`?  I have a 3rd party dev who needs access and I want to restrict root privileges for them.

I tried setting a password with `sudo passwd` but I still don't require a password.

```
~$ sudo passwd root
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
~$ sudo su
/home/ubuntu# exit
~$ sudo passwd
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
~$ sudo su
/home/ubuntu#
```

**UPDATE**

I tried requiring the password by running `sudo visudo` and adding:

```
ubuntu        ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

Now I'm asked for a password but the one which I set does not work!  Luckily I created an AMI before I started any of this.

Could the issue be that I don't have a password set for the `ubuntu` user, I should I have run `sudo passwd ubuntu` rather than `sudo passwd root`.

---

## FINAL SOLUTION

Just to clarify, my mistake was that I set the password for the wrong user, I tried to set it for *root* whereas I should have set it for *ubuntu* with:

```
~$ sudo passwd ubuntu
```

And then updating */etc/sudoers* so that the *ubuntu* user must give their password when running a `sudo` command. To edit this file you must run `sudo visudo` and add:

```
ubuntu        ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

Comment: I think the idea is that in order to get access to the root (ubuntu) user via SSH you would have had to already authenticate the session with the .pem hash, which is theoretically more secure than a password. So that is why they don't require a further password to assume super user privileges.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a line like

```
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

in /etc/sudoers, this will allow all users to sudo without being prompted for passwords. If you uncomment this line you will have to specify which users that are allowed to use sudo, for instance

```
myuser ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Comment: I just tried something similar to this, see my updated question. /etc/sudoers did not have `ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`  it had `myuser ALL=(ALL) ALL`

Comment: @SteffenNielson Could the issue be that I don't have a password set for the `ubuntu` user, I should I have run `sudo passwd ubuntu` rather than `sudo passwd root`.

Comment: From your post, i'm a little insecure if you are trying to use the root user's password when sudoing from "myuser". The idea with sudo is, that you will have to use the user's password itself. Are you doing so? You will definitely have to set a password for your "ubuntu" user with the cmd: sudo passwd ubuntu .

Comment: yes that was it, I was not setting the password on ubuntu.  It works nicely now.  If you have time would you mind joining me in this [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30246/questions-728831-setting-password-on-sudo-su-for-amazon-ec2-instance).  Out of curiosity I triied `su www-data` but this did not work, I wonder why

Comment: never mind I get that now too i.e. http://askubuntu.com/a/124069/138101

Answer (score 4):

Sudo will cache your credentials, so that if you use it multiple times within a short time period, it will only ask for your password the first time.

The man page says:

```
   timestamp_timeout
                     Number of minutes that can elapse before sudo will
                     ask for a passwd again.  The timeout may include a
                     fractional component if minute granularity is
                     insufficient, for example 2.5.  The default is 5.
                     Set this to 0 to always prompt for a password.  If
                     set to a value less than 0 the user's time stamp
                     will never expire.  This can be used to allow users
                     to create or delete their own time stamps via "sudo
                     -v" and "sudo -k" respectively.
```

So if you always want to request a password, you simply type `sudo visudo` to edit the file. Add this line:

```
Defaults        timestamp_timeout=0
```

This will require a password to be entered for all sudo commands.